# model Coin toss probability

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics

Model the probability of tossing any sequence of 8 heads and tails as equally likely. Take the sample space to be the set of the 256 possible sequences. What is the probability of the event that the sequence has at least two heads? (Hint: there are 9 sequences that have just 0 or one occurrence of heads: the sequence of just tails, together with the eight sequences with 7 tails and a head in position 1,2,38.)

Not looking for an answer but some clarification, my book is not very helpful on how I would use this information

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint1 : You have the Laplacian case : Every elementary event has the same 
        probability. You only have to count the number of elementary events
        leading to the desired event and the number of elementary events
        (which is $256$).

Hint2 : The event : $0$ heads or $1$ heads is complementary to the event :
        at least two heads.

Comment: sorry, I do not follow your hint.

Comment: Each possible sequence is an elementary event. And since each sequence has the same probability, each elementary event has the same probability.

Comment: So, if you know the number of sequences leading to the event : at least two heads , you only have to divide this number by $256$ to get the desired probability.

Comment: $9$ sequences do not lead to the event : at least two heads. So, how many sequences lead to it ?

Comment: so 27 events lead to it so 27/256. what do the positions 1,2,38 mean?

Comment: No, $256-9=247$ lead to the event : at least two heads.

Comment: ah I see so 247/256

Comment: That means, the the single throw head can occur in position $1$,$2$,$3$,...,$8$

Comment: Anything still unclear ?

Comment: I think I have it now. thanks